# Numpy: Select by index array along an axis

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I'd like to select elements from an array along a specific axis given an index array. For example, given the arrays

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape(5,2,3)
idx = np.array([0,1,1,0,0])
```

I'd like to select from the second dimension of `a` according to `idx`, such that the resulting array is of shape `(5,3)`. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use fancy indexing

```
a[np.arange(5),idx]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

To make this more verbose this is the same as:

```
x,y,z = np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx, slice(None)
a[x,y,z]
```

`x` and `y` are being broadcasted to the shape `(5,5)`. `z` could be used to select any columns in the output.

Comment: This works also: ```a[np.r_[:5], idx]```.

Answer (score 3):

I think this gives the results you are after - it uses [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html), but first you need to reshape your `idx` array so that it is also a 3d array:

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 2, 3)
idx = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0]).reshape(5, 1, 1)
results = np.take_along_axis(a, idx, 1).reshape(5, 3)
```

Giving:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [15 16 17]
 [18 19 20]
 [24 25 26]]
```